# setting emulator in android studio or use bluestack and how?

Tags: android, cordova, emulation

i have installed Cordova with andriod studio now when i am going to execute
this command on command prompt (inside my cordova project)

```
cordova run androird
```

build successfull but show an error 
no emulator images  found, if you would like to....

how to set emulator that show my app output or someone told me to install bluestack and use it as you emulator it fast. so what is best and how to do ?

Comment: start bluestack and reset adb

Comment: ok go to terminal do : --> adb kill-server and then --> adb start-server

Comment: blue stack is to much slow loading game data progress bar showing continuously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple from Android Studio go to your Toolbar and from AVD MAnager you will be able to create a new Emulator click on the create button or new button follow the steps fill in the forms and you will have your new emulator

[image]

EDIT

you can do this as a config for your emulator
[image]

For installing Image

[image]

Comment: what are the specification i need to add? here i found it in TOOLs->Andriod->AVD Manager

Comment: good + from me but i dont have image installed thats why ok is disable  i guess

Comment: which one option for emulator